# How to print float to n decimal places including trailing 0s?

Tags: python, floating-point

I need to print or convert a float number to 15 decimal place string even if the result has many trailing 0s eg:

1.6 becomes 1.6000000000000000

I tried round(6.2,15) but it returns 6.2000000000000002 adding a rounding error

I also saw various people online who put the float into a string and then added trailing 0's manually but that seems bad...

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Side note, but that last 2 is not a rounding error exactly. The number 6.2, like many other real numbers, is not exactly representable with a floating point variable in a computer. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary for more information.

Comment: @mtrw, I think you could get away with calling it a rounding error - the input is being rounded to the closest binary number.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

### For Python versions in 2.6+ and 3.x

You can use the [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method. Examples:

```
>>> print('{0:.16f}'.format(1.6))
1.6000000000000001

>>> print('{0:.15f}'.format(1.6))
1.600000000000000
```

Note the `1` at the end of the first example is rounding error; it happens because exact representation of the decimal number 1.6 requires an infinite number binary digits. Since floating-point numbers have a finite number of bits, the number is rounded to a nearby, but not equal, value.

### For Python versions prior to 2.6 (at least back to 2.0)

You can use the "modulo-formatting" syntax (this works for Python 2.6 and 2.7 too):

```
>>> print '%.16f' % 1.6
1.6000000000000001

>>> print '%.15f' % 1.6
1.600000000000000
```

Comment: +1. This answer works in >= Python 2.7. In Python 2.6 it would be `'{0:.16f}'.format(x)`, not sure about older Python.

Comment: @mtrw Good point. The "modulo-formatting" (e.g., `'%.16f' % 1.6`) works at least back to Python 2.0 ([Python 2.0 String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/release/2.0/lib/typesseq-strings.html)).

Comment: i get a weird error when i try the above code:

`# Error: ValueError: zero length field name in format #`

Comment: @jonathantopf Which version of Python do you have? As @mtrw pointed out in a comment above, if you have Python 2.6, you need the positional argument (the `0` in the code of that comment). This is also true if you have Python 3.0.

Comment: @mtrw I updated the answer to use the positional argument and include the "modulo-formatting" for pre-2.6 interpreters.

Comment: While this answer is technically true and informative, I do feel it is missing the point of the question.  If you `print '{0:.15f}'.format(600.2)` you will notice already non-zero numbers creeping in from the right, and the larger your number, the more "noise" you will see in the decimals.  See my answer about using the `decimal` module if you truly care about maintaining 15 digit precision.

Comment: I get Syntax errors in Python 3.7 due to lack of brackets. I've added them in

Answer (score 17):

The cleanest way in modern Python `>=3.6`, is to use an f-string with [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> var = 1.6
>>> f"{var:.16f}"
'1.6000000000000001'
```

If you want to "avoid" the last `1`, which occurs at the 15th decimal place because of how floating point numbers work, you can convert the `float` first into a string and then into a `Decimal`:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> f"{Decimal(str(var)):.16f}"
'1.6000000000000000'
```

Note that if you are working with numbers that need 15 decimal places of precision, you should not be using `float`s in the first place but should build your solution around `Decimal`s from the get-go.

Answer (score 5):

Floating point numbers lack precision to accurately represent "1.6" out to that many decimal places.  The rounding errors are real.  Your number is not actually 1.6.

Check out: http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is essentially putting it in a string, but this avoids the rounding error:

```
import decimal

def display(x):
    digits = 15
    temp = str(decimal.Decimal(str(x) + '0' * digits))
    return temp[:temp.find('.') + digits + 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `format()` to print digits after the decimal places.
Taken from http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

```
>>> format(math.pi, '.12g')  # give 12 significant digits
'3.14159265359'

>>> format(math.pi, '.2f')   # give 2 digits after the point
'3.14'
```

Comment: It's not true that '.12g' always gives 12 significant digits:


`>>> f'{1.23456:.12g}' 
'1.23456'`