# Rounding Hypocritical?

Tags: python, rounding

I couldn't think of a better name. Please feel free to edit. On Python, I tried rounding the number 6.2 to 15 decimal places after seeing [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568233/print-float-to-n-decimal-places-including-trailing-0s) and got:

```
   round(6.2,15)
   => 6.2000000000000002
```

Great! Now I try the **same** thing for 1.2 and:

```
   round(1.2,15)
   => 1.2
```

Huh? That's my only reaction.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the string format:

```
"{:.15f}".format(1.2)
```

Maybe next article can help:

Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations
http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html