# why int(12) becomes 11

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7. Here is the code and output, my purpose is simply to check if a number is a cube number.

**Source code**,

```
x = 1728 ** (1.0/3)
print x
y = int(x)
print y
```

**Output**,

```
12.0
11
```

Comment: `x` is perhaps `11.9999...something`.

Comment: I suggest that you learn about the general concerns of representing floating point numbers in computer hardware and software. You should also read about Python-specific issues as well.

Comment: @AlexD, if so, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Resolving the issue is highly dependent on your real use-case.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I just want to check if a number is a cube number.

Comment: You should consider going the opposite direction and actually cube integers instead of taking the cube root. The trade off is that this will be less efficient while avoiding accuracy issues. Of course, if you are doing this repeatedly, you should create a list of cubes so that you don't have to recompute them every time.

Comment: Note that `int(12)` as you describe in the title does not actually appear in your code. `int(12)` is indeed 12.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I mean this line `y = int(x)`, where `x` is `12.0`, any thoughts why `y` becomes `11` other than `12`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I like your approach. But just got stuck in my issue, `y = int(x)`, where `x` is `12.0`, any thoughts why `y` becomes `11` other than `12`?

Comment: Again, `x` is neither 12 nor 12.0. It is another number entirely. The question's title is misleading.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, what is the actual value do you mean? I said it is `12.0` from print output.

Comment: `print` gives an approximation. You have to [specify when you want to display more precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568233/print-float-to-n-decimal-places-including-trailing-0s).

Comment: "any thoughts why y becomes 11 other than 12" The first two comments from AlexD and myself already address this.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're using floating points, and the result is some very very small fraction less than 12, and when you cast x to an int, the entire decimal portion of the number is discarded.

If what you want to do is *round* the number, use `round()`.

Comment: Thanks furkle, do you have any elegant ways to check if a number is a cube number?

Comment: Thanks, but `round` will return the nearest number, how could it be used to check if a number is a cube number?

Comment: @LinMa I would suggest opening a new question for that -- you're likely to get more info specific to that problem and not the vagaries of floating-point math in Python 2.x.

Comment: Sure, just to confirm, in my specific problem, `11` is returned since `int` gets the floor, other than round to nearest number?