# Enforce that numeric output has at least two trailing decimal places, including trailing zeros

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, decimal-point

I have a Python script that produces the following output:

```
31.7
31.71
31.72
31.73
31.74
31.75
31.76
31.77
31.78
31.79
31.8
31.81
31.82
31.83
31.84
31.85
31.86
31.87
31.88
31.89
31.9
31.91
```

Please note the numbers `31.7`, `31.8`, `31.9`.

The purpose of my script is to determine numeric palindromes, such as `1.01`.

The problem with the script (*reproduced below*) is that it will evaluate numeric palindromes such as `1.1` as valid- **however**- that is *not* considered to be valid output in this situation.

Valid output needs to have exactly **two** decimal places.

How to enforce that the numeric output has at least two trailing decimal places, including trailing zeros?

```
import sys

# This method determines whether or not the number is a Palindrome
def isPalindrome(x):
    x = str(x).replace('.','')
    a, z = 0, len(x) - 1
    while a < z:
        if x[a] != x[z]:
            return False
        a += 1
        z -= 1
    return True

if '__main__' == __name__:

    trial = float(sys.argv[1])

    operand = float(sys.argv[2])

    candidrome = trial + (trial * 0.15)

    print(candidrome)
    candidrome = round(candidrome, 2)

    # check whether we have a Palindrome
    while not isPalindrome(candidrome):
        candidrome = candidrome + (0.01 * operand)
        candidrome = round(candidrome, 2)
        print(candidrome)

    if isPalindrome(candidrome):
        print( "It's a Palindrome! " + str(candidrome) )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print float to n decimal places including trailing 0's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568233/print-float-to-n-decimal-places-including-trailing-0s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the builtin [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) function. `.2` refers to the number of digits, and `f` refers to "float".

```
if isPalindrome(candidrome):
    print("It's a Palindrome! " + format(candidrome, '.2f'))
```

Or:

```
if isPalindrome(candidrome):
    print("It's a Palindrome! %.2f" % candidrome)
```

Comment: does this turn it into a string?

Comment: @s.matthew.english: Yes it does. Something like `format(0.666666, '.2f')` will return `'0.67'`.

Comment: but I need it to be as a float so I can pipe it back into the function and make it a palindrome

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of `str(x)`:

```
twodec = '{:.2f}'.format(x)
```

Comment: I still see the pernicious  non-trailing-zeroers, like this `3.2`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
data = """
    1.7
    31.71
    31.72
    31.73
  """
new_data = data.split('\n')
palindromes = [i for i in new_data if len(i) > 3 and i.replace('.', '') == i.replace('.', '')[::-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ("%.2f" % x).replace('.','')
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)