# Python decimal value handling

Tags: python, python-2.7

How are floating point numbers handled in python. I am using a simple telegram bot.

```
import telegram

value=0.0000023
bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=value)
```

I am getting `2.3e-06`. Even print also gives `2.3e-06`. How do I get `0.0000023`. How can I handle decimal values out to at least 20 zeros.

Comment: 2.3e-06 and 0.0000023 are the same number. If you care about exact sequences of characters, it may be more appropriate to use a type that represents sequences of characters (`str`), rather than a type that represents numbers (`float`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print float to n decimal places including trailing 0's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568233/print-float-to-n-decimal-places-including-trailing-0s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can just use `format` and specify that you want 20 decimal places but that will be pretty ugly.

```
>>> format(2.3e-06, ".20f")
'0.00000230000000000000'
```

But what you can do is use that string and then clean up all of the zeros on the right side using `rstrip`

```
>>> format(2.3e-06, ".20f").rstrip("0")
'0.0000023'
>>> format(2.3e-16, ".20f").rstrip("0")
'0.00000000000000023'
```

Then the only thing left is to figure out if a number is less than 10^-20 and if it is then just print it using the normal exponential formatting that Python will do anyway.

```
def format_for_up_to_n_decimal_places(num, n_decimal_places):
    if num < 10**-n_decimal_places:
        return str(num)
    else:
        return format(num, ".{}f".format(n_decimal_places)).rstrip('0')
```

Example:

```
>>> format_for_up_to_n_decimal_places(2.3e-6, 20)
'0.0000023'
>>> format_for_up_to_n_decimal_places(2.3e-50, 20)
'2.3e-50'
```