# Controlling decimals rather than significant digits in Python

Tags: python, formatting, decimal, digits

I have code for an assignment that returns a *float*, but for visual consistency I'd like to format the output in a very specific way. For example, when I call my method...

```
return my_variable
```

The unformatted output looks like,

```
0.00014403540291982756644
```

I tried using f-string to limit the output to 2 decimals.

```
return f'{my_variable:.2}'
```

For which I get,

```
0.00014
```

I know it's **very** odd, but I'd like the output to be,

```
0.00
```

Can this be done? Also, for the purpose of the assignment, I can only use standard Python libraries. Note, this is not a trailing zeros question like this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568233/print-float-to-n-decimal-places-including-trailing-0s).

Comment: This is the formatting you need `.2f`

Comment: That did it. Thank you!