# Is it possible to have more than 15 decimal digits in a float without Decimal module?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

Is it possible to store more than 15 digits in a `float`. 
For example, I have this `float phi`.

Example:

```py
phi = 21.618033988749894848204586834365 # 30 decimal digits

print(phi) # -> ~21.618033988749893, 15 imprecise decimal digits
```

How can I guarantee I get more than 15 *accurate* digits from this float, without using the `Decimal` class?

*NOTE: I know that this is not applicable, as `Decimal` is built into Python. I am leaving it open for reference to others with a similar situation, not realizing `Decimal` is a builtin.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print float to n decimal places including trailing 0s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568233/how-to-print-float-to-n-decimal-places-including-trailing-0s)

Answer (score 2):

Floats are fixed-precision. They physically cannot store the amount of data you're trying to stuff into them. You will have to use an arbitrary-precision data type; `decimal.Decimal` is one, but there are others that may be more useful depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to avoid having any or at least not many external modules in my code. I have been able to limit it to just typing, and I would like to keep it that way.

Comment: @CATboardBETA: `decimal` and `typing` are both standard library modules. Using them does not add any dependencies to your code.

Comment: Oh. I knew that was the case with typing, but was unaware it was with decimal. To clarify also, if in my input for a function I had `Union[float, SupportsFloat]`, it would support decimal, correct?

Comment: @CATboardBETA: Technically, but that annotation suggests you're planning to call `float` on the input, which would throw away all the extra precision you want.

Comment: Actually, I'll just do `Union[float, decimal]`, because I too stupid to think of that before.